# Candidate SE site for asking about AGT Magics tricks

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have seen some videos of Got Talent like this :

[image]

It seems there are some missed frames there, so AGT‌ (American Got Talent) has [High Speed Cameras](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=21&ved=2ahUKEwiS7t211d7nAhWFjKQKHaaaBTkQFjAUegQISxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHigh-speed_camera&usg=AOvVaw3D0dxtKbuBqLB1hi6DYDdk&rct=j&esrc=s). How is possible to do this work which is common in another clothes changing scenes in AGT like this:

[image]

There are some bolder magics which I like to find their tricks which could be in different pseudoscience or scientific area.

Which site should I be asking about AGT Magics tricks (for example fast changing clothes)?

Answer (score 4):

That first one is simply a camera trick - it is very unlike the second one which is a popular branch of entertainment.

Your post is far too broad. Magic is a huge discipline, and there is no magic.se, so you will not find answers here.

If you want to know more about them, look up "Quick Change" routines, and in fact all branches of magic are well served by the internet.